# Equation Containing a Series (Perhaps with Explicit Form)

Tags: sequences-and-series, bessel-functions

I need to solve the following equation for $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$:
$$\alpha+\frac{\lambda}{4\pi}+\frac{i}{4}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{J_{n}(iR\lambda)}{H_{n}^{(1)}(iR\lambda)}(H_{n}^{(1)}(i\rho\lambda))^{2}=0$$
Here $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, $0<R<\rho$, $J_{n}$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of order $n$ and$H_{n}^{(1)}$ is the Hankel function of order $n$.

Moreover $\lambda$ must lie in the region $-\pi<\text{Arg}(\lambda)\le\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Maybe there is a closed form for the sum, but could not find it. I wondered also if I could expand the two linear terms in some Bessel function based series and find a set of recurring equation to solve the problem.

Any insight is appreciated.
Thank you.